# Use Redux connect in React HOC

Tags: reactjs, redux, connect

I have react HOC for `sessionTimeout`. Now I want to Redux connect for use redux action method.

When I call method `this.props.actions.logout` It throws error Undefined.

How I suppose to connect redux in my HOC

**HOC**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'antd';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

export default function(ComposedClass){
 return class extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      warningTime: 4000,
      signoutTime: 5000,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.events = [
      'load',
      'mousemove',
      'mousedown',
      'click',
      'scroll',
      'keypress'
    ];

    for (var i in this.events) {
      window.addEventListener(this.events[i], this.resetTimeout);
    }

    this.setTimeout();
  }

  clearTimeoutFunc = () => {
    if (this.warnTimeout) clearTimeout(this.warnTimeout);
    if (this.logoutTimeout) clearTimeout(this.logoutTimeout);
  };

  setTimeout = () => {
    this.warnTimeout = setTimeout(this.warn, this.state.warningTime);
    this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(this.logout, this.state.signoutTime);
  };

  resetTimeout = () => {
    this.clearTimeoutFunc();
    this.setTimeout();
  };

  warn = () => {
    Modal.warning({
      title: 'Session Timeout',
      content: 'Your session is about to expire in 1 mintue',
    });
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.props.actions.logout()
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <ComposedClass {...this.props} />
      </div>
    );

  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can connect the component within the HOC and return the connected component from it

```
export default function(ComposedClass){

    class Component extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          warningTime: 4000,
          signoutTime: 5000,
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.events = [
          'load',
          'mousemove',
          'mousedown',
          'click',
          'scroll',
          'keypress'
        ];

        for (var i in this.events) {
          window.addEventListener(this.events[i], this.resetTimeout);
        }

        this.setTimeout();
      }

      clearTimeoutFunc = () => {
        if (this.warnTimeout) clearTimeout(this.warnTimeout);
        if (this.logoutTimeout) clearTimeout(this.logoutTimeout);
      };

      setTimeout = () => {
        this.warnTimeout = setTimeout(this.warn, this.state.warningTime);
        this.logoutTimeout = setTimeout(this.logout, this.state.signoutTime);
      };

      resetTimeout = () => {
        this.clearTimeoutFunc();
        this.setTimeout();
      };

      warn = () => {
        Modal.warning({
          title: 'Session Timeout',
          content: 'Your session is about to expire in 1 mintue',
        });
      };

      logout = () => {
        this.props.actions.logout()
      };

      render() {

        return (
          <div>
            <ComposedClass {...this.props} />
          </div>
        );

      }
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
}
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Comment: Ok, you needed to make it fixed for redux. In that case this is better solution. But it doesnt give you flexibility to go with redux or any other state management. Have fun :)

Comment: @MarioPetrovic, Generally you would connect the container and pass on the required data as props to the component created by HOC. That would give you flexibility, however OP use case was a little different

Comment: Yep, that is true

Comment: Will this HOC call in all the components? Becoz I see It working in all components. In login component also

Comment: In my Route I'm using this way  `path="/Dashboard" component={SessionTimeout(Dashboard)}` Is this correct?

Comment: @Selvin, yes, whereever this HOC is used, in all of those components it will take the data from Redux store

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri SessionTimeout works and also redirect to login as expected. But login component also shows same sessiontimeout warning.

Comment: @Selvin, In such a case you would need to write a HOC differently for login component

Comment: Hey I had one doubt. When redux store gets updated, does this class's `render` lifecycle will be called again ?

Comment: Also is this a valid practice as there is authorization wrapper in my whole `<Route>` structure ?